# How to Filter a search using key words in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm already aware of using categories to filter a search in a swift table, I am looking to filter a search where there may be multiple key words for one particular search.

Currently I have a class as follows:

```
class Video {

    var videoName: String
    var videoTags: [String]


    init(name: String, tags: [String]) {
        self.videoName = name
        self.videoTags = tags

    }
}
```

As far as I understand it, if I use a single String for Tag I could create categories for searching, however in this scenario there are multiple tags (i.e. "tutorial", "advice" etc..)

How can I create a search bar that will show the correct video name in the table, depending on which key word the user has typed in?

Comment: Unrelated but those `vars` can be replaced with `let`s (prefer immutability)

Comment: Thank you, I am still new to this and generally type var from habit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class Video {

    var videoName: String
    var videoTags: [String]

    init(name: String, tags: [String]) {
        self.videoName = name
        self.videoTags = tags

    }
}

var videos: [Video] = [Video(name: "First Video", tags: ["First", "Advice"]),Video(name: "Second Video", tags: ["Second", "Tutorial"]), Video(name: "Third Video", tags: ["Third", "Tutorial"])]

func filterVideos(tag: String)-> [Video] {
    return videos.filter { (video) -> Bool in
        for _tag in video.videoTags {
            if _tag.lowercased().contains(tag.lowercased()) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

let filtered = filterVideos(tag: "Tuto") // <= this will contain Second Video And Third Video
```

Comment: Simpler: `return videos.filter{ video in video.videoTags.contains(where: { $0.lowercased() == tag.lowercased() }) }`

Comment: @Alexander, your solution will return some value only if keyword will be equal to tag... so, for keyword "Tuto" your solution will return nothing(Empty array). This is not simpler, this is different.

Comment: oops, I didn't mean to change `.contains()` to `==`. This is what my first comment should have been: `return videos.filter{ video in video.videoTags.contains(where: { $0.lowercased().contains(tag.lowercased()) }) }`

Comment: @Alexander, now I'm agree with you)

Answer (score 0):

filteredArray = userList.filter { $0.first_name.range(of: txtSearch.text! , options: .caseInsensitive) != nil || $0.last_name.range(of: txtSearch.text! , options: .caseInsensitive) != nil || $0.department.range(of: txtSearch.text! , options: .caseInsensitive) != nil

Comment: In above code there are two array one is USER LIST that contains first_name , last_name & department from which we filtering the records in another array named FILTEREDArray using filter Method